# Obrigar a importação de css e js em páginas do site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<nav class="navmenu center">
   <ul>
      <li class="first scroll_btn active" onclick="atualizarPagina('Home.htm');"> <a>Home</a></li>
      <li class="scroll_btn" onclick="atualizarPagina('Empresa.htm');"><a>Empresa</a></li>
      <li class="scroll_btn" onclick="atualizarPagina('Servicos.htm');"><a>Serviços</a></li>
      <li class="scroll_btn" onclick="atualizarPagina('Contato.htm');"><a>Fale Conosco</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="conteudoHome">
   ...
</div>

<div id="conteudo">

</div>


    function atualizarPagina(site) {
        if (site == "Home.htm") {
            $("#conteudoHome").css("display", "block");
            $("#conteudo").css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            $("#conteudoHome").css("display", "none");
            $("#conteudo").css("display", "block");
            $.get(site, function (data) {
                $("#conteudo").html(data);
            });
        }
        void (0);
        scroll(0, 0);
    }
```

Toda página, por exemplo Empresa.htm, tem apenas um html do container.

Assim quando o usuário acessa o site como www.x.com.br/Empresa.htm, ele não importa os css e os js do index, e perde toda a formatação do site.

Queria saber como fazer com que ao acessar www.x.com.br/Empresa.htm, importasse todo o css e o js.

E aproveitando a pergunta, queria saber se esse tipo de site (não contendo uma estrutura completa para cada página) compromete alguma coisa do SEO, como indexação do google essas coisas, porque li em alguns lugares que afetam o SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível "herdar" essa estrutura com HTML puro. Você vai precisar ou de algum mecanismo do lado do servidor (como [MasterPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx), em C#), ou, o mais próximo disso que você consegue chegar no lado do cliente é usando uma plataforma estilo [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) para os seus JavaScripts e algo como `@import` de CSS para os seus estilos.

Sobre o Backbone, isso não é assunto para esta resposta – se quiser saber mais, acesse o site oficial e leia sobre; sobre o `@import` do CSS, você pode fazer uma folha **/css/empresa.css** da seguinte forma:

```
@import url("main.css");

#conteudo {
    font-size: 16px
}
```

No mesmo nível de pasta, o arquivo **main.css**:

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

E então, em **Empresa.htm** referenciar da seguinte forma:

```
<!-- ... -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/empresa.css">
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: O uso de masterpage é uma melhor opção, no site em geral?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Baseado no seu problema, é a melhor das soluções por mim apresentadas. Você está usando C#? Se sim, sem dúvidas é a melhor opção.

Comment: Prefira sempre carregar um arquivo CSS usando <link> do que '@import'.
Quando você utiliza '@import' opção a partir de uma folha de estilo externa, o navegador é incapaz de realizar o download em paralelo, o que causa atraso na cascata de carregamento dos arquivos.  fonte : http://browserdiet.com/pt/#prefer-link-over-import